# Problem creating Flutter app via Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

Problem creating Flutter app via Android Studio
[image]

Comment: don't use upper case. as mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [dart documentation on naming packages](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-libraries-and-source-files-using-lowercase_with_underscores) change the name of your project to `salam`

```
DO name libraries, packages, directories,
and source files using lowercase_with_underscores.
```

So consider this in your case and your future apps.